# Pull pagespeed in seconds from Chrome User Experience Report into a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-pagespeed

By following the guide [Create Your Own Google Pagespeed & Mobile Usability Tracking Google Sheet in 5 Steps](https://cagrisarigoz.com/2015/07/10/create-your-own-google-pagespeed-and-mobile-usability-tracking-googlesheet-in-5-steps/) I managed to set up mobile pagespeed score for a list of (up to 50) URLs.

However since late 2017 or something there is real data available from the [Chrome User Experience Report](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/) that displays an average load time in seconds for a page based on chrome user data.
(This data is being used for example when using [Pagespeed Insights by google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).)

Instead of pulling a page score I as described above I would like to pull the average load time into my google sheet.

Is it possible to adapt the script used from the article above to pull load time in seconds instead of pagescore? Or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance your help is much appreciated.

This is the script I run in script editor to get pagescore into google sheet according to the linked article with function `=checkAll(C3)`:

```
 /**
 * Returns Mobile Pagespeed, Mobile Usability, and Desktop Pagespeed values in three adjacent columns
 * by Cagri Sarigoz
 */

function checkAll(Url) {

  //CHANGE YOUR API KEY WITH YOUR_API_KEY BELOW
  var key = "AIzaSyB2SeOumbCd6YNfFWRg5Jo_WpISZi4gCFs";
  var serviceUrlMobile = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url="+Url+"&strategy=mobile&key="+key;
  var serviceUrlDesktop = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url="+Url+"&strategy=desktop&key="+key;
  var array = [];

  if (key == "YOUR_API_KEY")
    return "Please enter your API key to the script";  

  var responseMobile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrlMobile);

  if(responseMobile.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var contentMobile = JSON.parse(responseMobile.getContentText());

    if ( (contentMobile != null) && (contentMobile["ruleGroups"] != null) )
    {
      if (contentMobile["responseCode"] == 200)
              {
        var speedScoreMobile = contentMobile["ruleGroups"]["SPEED"]["score"];
        var usabilityScoreMobile = contentMobile["ruleGroups"]["USABILITY"]["score"];
      }
      else
      {
          array.push(["Not Found!", "Not Found!", "Not Found!"]);
          return array;
      }
    }
  }

  var responseDesktop = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrlDesktop);

  if(responseDesktop.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var contentDesktop = JSON.parse(responseDesktop.getContentText());

    if ( (contentDesktop != null) && (contentDesktop["ruleGroups"] != null) )
      var speedScoreDesktop = contentDesktop["ruleGroups"]["SPEED"]["score"];  
  }
  array.push([speedScoreMobile, usabilityScoreMobile, speedScoreDesktop]);
  return array;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the writer of the blog post that you shared. As you said, the Google Apps Script there was using Google Pagespeed API v2. The current API version is v4, and v2 will be depreciated on June 30th.

So I updated the code with v4 on my own copy of the spreadsheet. You can make your own copy from [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zn8ANJQz5JQABWiosT6RKtNtT8Er08gkKwv3H7KVArM/edit?usp=sharing).

I also wanted to add the mobile-friendly test results but it turned out that Google Search Console's API quota restrictions were too tight, returning error almost all the time. So I commented out that part of the code for the time being.

I didn't have the time to update my blog post yet. You can see the new version of the script [here](https://gist.github.com/csarigoz/76777a4743bfa8bed491).

Comment: Wow @Cagri Sarigoz That is awesome, thank you very much for giving me a hand! Your solution works excellent! What I am wondering is if there is a way to somehow compare pagespeed of individual pages (perhaps by pulling speed from chrome dev tools somehow?). Because now I can compare different domains but for each URL of a single domain of course the same pagespeed is displayed. Do you have any further idea on this? Thanks, your help and script is much appreciated!